# Why can a kafka topic only be reset to earliest offset if it is DEAD or EMPTY?

Tags: apache-kafka

When running the CLI command `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server $server --group $group --topic $topic --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute`, the [resetOffsets()](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.6/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L421) function in `kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand` is executed.

In this function the actual reset is only done if the [ConsumerGroupState is Dead or Empty](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.6/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L435).  What is the implication of this?  Why won't the offset be reset if the state is e.g. `Stable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a consumer actively polling or committing offsets to that group, so an active consumer in a group forms a type of lock, preventing offsets from externally being reset.

To work around this, you should call `seekToBeginning` + `commitSync` in the consumer code itself.

Comment: Thanks! I guess an alternative would be to stop the consumer(s) before resetting the offset.

Comment: Sure, but that's not always an option (e.g. consumers are ran by another team)